# use existing variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to leave out the variable assignment from a for loop and do something like this…?

```
otherVar = 3;

for ( otherVar > 0; otherVar-- )
{
    stuff
}
```

Comment: You can also declare a bunch of vars right in the loop:

for(var someVar=0, otherVar=3, yetAnother='bob';yetAnother!==false;someVar++)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but you need to put in the semi-colon:

```
var otherVar = 3;

for ( ; otherVar > 0; otherVar-- ) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually While is more popular for this situation (better readability)..

```
otherVar = 3;

while ( otherVar > 0)
{
   stuff
   otherVar--;
}
```

Comment: Ah, decided to do it your way. Not sure why I was trying to use a for loop. :)

Comment: Happy to help:). shorthand for the while condition is 
while( otherVar-- > 0 ) in case if don't like to use incrementation  at the end of the loop. Btw, +1 is a good way to mention that the answer was useful here in SO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can count down from any arbitrary number:

```
var counter = 3;
while ( counter-- ) {
  console.log( counter );
}
```

Which outputs: 2, 1, 0

Comment: Just a quick question. Correct me if I'm wrong but the while loop runs till the expression inside the parentheses is true right. when does counter-- become false or true.